# Prove that for every positive integer, this polynomial is divisible by 24.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Prove that:
>   $$24\mid n^4 + 2n^3 - n^2 - 2n, \quad \forall n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$$

I tried to prove it, but had no luck.

Comment: i tried by a common factor..i don't know what to do next

Comment: You need to show 1) That it is divisible by $3$, and 2) that it's divisible by $8$.

Comment: "Whenever in doubt, factor it out" Your polynomial in $n$ is extremely factorable and it is begging for it...

Comment: how do i show (in a test) that (n−1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)is divisible by 8?

Comment: Probably the reason why some people down-voted this question and some voted to close it is that you haven't explained the nature of your attempts to solve this problem, and the point at which you got stuck. They ought to explain that here in comments, but usually they don't. $\qquad$

Comment: @AlonBerman : I think my answer may be the most elementary of those posted so far, using essentially no algebra except the factorization that you've already mentioned (i.e. $(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $f(n)=(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$; also, $24=4!=4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1$. Can you continue now? See first take $n^3$ common from $n^4,2n^3$ and $-n$ common from $-n^2-2n$ then you get $(n^3-n)(n-2)$ now take $n$ comon from $n^3-n$ so you get $n(n^2-1)$ thus use $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$ to get $(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$

Comment: i got this: $$n\left( { n }^{ 3 }+2{ n }^{ 2 }-n-2 \right) $$ how do i continue from here to your solution?

Comment: Take base case with $n=2$ assume true for $k$ prove for $k+1$

Comment: no, i don't want to use induction..i want to reach the expression you wrote from the expression i got..

Comment: @AlonBerman You don't have to use induction. You've covered basic modular arithmetic in class, right?

Comment: Ill put it in my answer

Comment: tnx..ill be happy, i just need to see the solution in steps so i can tell you if i know this method

Comment: hi thanks for all the answers i finally resolved the problem in this question can you please close my question

Answer (score 1):

Reduce mod $3$ and mod $8$ separately, or use the fact that the given polynomial is just $24\binom{n+2}{4}$. (As a bit of an explanation for the latter, note that any integer-valued polynomial $P(n)$ is an integer combination of binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}$.)

Comment: $n^4+2 n^3-n^2-2 n= $ $n\cdot (n^3+2 n^2-n-2)=$ $n\cdot (n^3-n +2 n^2-2)=$ $n\cdot ([n(n^2-1]+2[n^2-1])=$ $n\cdot [n+2][n^2-1]=$ $n\cdot  [n+2][n+1][n-1]=$ $(n-1) n (n+1)(n+2).$

Comment: @user254665: I'm afraid I'm not sure what the point of your comment is.

Comment: the OP asked in a comment to another q about how  the factoring was achieved.

Comment: Ah, didn't see the other comments.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, factor $n^4+2n^3-n^2-2n$ into terms with the lowest power possible- in this case, power $1$. A heuristic would be to group the even powered terms together, and the odd power terms together; doing this, we get:

$$n^2(n^2-1)+2n(n^2-1)$$
$$\implies (n^2+2n)(n^2-1)$$
Breaking it down further from here, we then get
$$n(n+2)(n-1)(n+1).$$
Curiously, we rearrange these terms to find
$$(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2),$$
which is an abstraction for $4$ consecutive integers.
Note that for any 3 consecutive integers $k$, $k+1$, and $k+2$, their product $p=k(k+1)(k+2)$ [is divisible by 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20180128025852/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/61347.html). From these four consecutive integers, can you show that 8 must divide two of them? If so, your proof is complete.

Comment: hey, i don't understand how to get this: $n^2(n^2-1)+2n(n^2-1)$ i never heard about this method..can you explain it pls?

Comment: ohh..i understand now..tnx alot!

Comment: @AlonBerman You are welcome

Comment: how do i show (in a test) that $(n-1)(n)(n+1)(n+2)$ is divisible by 8?

Comment: If x is even then one of x, x+2 is divisible by 4 and the other by 2 so 8 divides x(x+2).  If if n-1  is even let x=n-1 and x+2=n+1.  If n is even let x=n and x+2=n+2. So 8 divides the product of 4 consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from clever answers given, the following  **tedious** method generally **works**: every integer $n$ can be written as $n=24k+m$, with  $0\le m\le 23$. When you expand $n^p$ with Newton formula, every cross-term with at least a power of $(24k)$ can be divided by $24$. So only the $p$-th power of $m$ remains.

Hence, it suffices to verify your equation $m^4+2m^3−m^2−2m$, only for each $0\le m\le 23$, and this will prove the result for all integers. For instance, if $m=3$, this yields: $81+2\times 27-9-6=120 = 5\times 24$.

This is tedious as announced, but intermediate calculations may help you understand that some factoring can be done. For  instance, if you do it  by hand, $23^4$ or $23^2$ might seem super-tedious. So you begin to see lazy spots: $m^4−m^2$ can be turned into $m^2(m^2-1)$. You only have to compute squares. And $2m^3−2m = 2m(m^2 -1)$. Oh wait, there is a common factor: $(m^2-1)$! Let us factor it further: $(m^2-1)(m^2-2m)$. And so on, you see the $m$ factor: $(m^2-1)(m^2-2m)=m(m^2-1)(m-2)=m(m-1)(m+1)(m-2)$. Then you recognize a product of four consecutive numbers. Like $\{1,2,3,4\}$, of product $24$. Like $\{2,3,4,5\}$, of product $120$. Like $\{3,4,5,6\}$, of product $360$.

In a series of four consecutive terms, $2$ terms are even, and obviously one of those two is a multiple of $4$. So the product is likely to me divided by $8$. And there is at least one multiple of $3$. And $8$ and $3$ are relative primes. You are almost done. 
So, the moral is: **when you have trouble finding out what a series does, it is always beneficial to compute the first terms**, to see what happen. And by computing them by hand, you get free training. And you might find unexpected patterns that will help you find a clever answer on the way.

Answer (score 0):

$$
n^4 + 2n^3 - n^2 - 2n = \underbrace{(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)}_\text{four consecutive integers}
$$
The four factors are four consecutive integers.  Either the first and third are even, or the second and fourth are even.  There you have two consecutive even integers.  One of those is a multiple of $4$, since in every sequence of four consecutive integers, exactly one is a multiple of $4$ (just as, for example, in every sequence of seven consecutive days, exactly one is a Thursday).  So you have a multiple of $4$ multiplied by another even number, and that gives you a multiple of $8$.

In every sequence of three consecutive integers, exactly one is a multiple of $3$.  That means you have at least one multiple of $3$ among the four factors.  (If the first or the fourth is a multiple of $3$, then both of them are, since they differ by $3$; otherwise just the second or the third is a multiple of $3$.)

Since $8$ and $3$ have no factors in common (besides the trivial factor, which is $1$), if a number is divisible by both $8$ and $3$, then it is divisible by $8\times 3$.